# impossible type switch case: ErrorType (type reflect.Type) cannot have dynamic type *os.SyscallError (missing Align method)

Tags: go

Trying to determine what the connect error is and return value back to program.

```
d := net.Dialer{Timeout: 20*time.Second}
conn, errors := d.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", host, port))
if errors != nil {
    if oerr, ok := errors.(*net.OpError); ok {
        ErrorType := reflect.TypeOf(oerr.Err)
        switch ErrorType.(type) {
            case *os.SyscallError:
                fmt.Println("connect: connection timed out to", host, "on port", port )
            case *poll.TimeoutError:
                fmt.Println("connect: connection refused to", host, "on port", port )
            default:
                panic("Unknown connection errot")
        }
    }
} else {
    fmt.Println("connect: connection successful to", host, "on port", port )
}

if conn != nil {
    conn.Close()
}
```

Get the follow error
**# command-line-arguments
./main.go:33:9: impossible type switch case: ErrorType (type reflect.Type) cannot have dynamic type *os.SyscallError (missing Align method)
./main.go:35:15: undefined: poll**

Comment: No need for that reflect thing that you're doing, simply do `switch oerr.Err.(type) {`.

Comment: Just FYI, what the error you're getting means is that when you do a `type switch`, the types you list in the `case expressions` **must** implement the interface on which you're doing the type switch. Since you're doing the type switch on a `reflect.Type` value, all of the types that you list in the case expressions must implement the `reflect.Type` interface, `*os.SyscallError` does not implement that interface and so the compiler blows up.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have no need to use reflect here. You need just type assertion language construction:

```
    conn, errors := d.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", host, port))
    if oerr, ok := errors.(*net.OpError); ok {
        switch oerr.Err.(type) {
        case os.SyscallError:
         ...
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind, you can't case the poll.TimeoutError because the poll package is internal and you can't import it. 
Regardless of all the above, if you want to check, if the error is related to timeout you should use Timeout method which is defined on the net.OpError

Comment: Could you give me an example of using the Timeout method.

Comment: I am new to Go, I wrote a similar program in Python which works but I like the ability to create object code and not have to worry about pip installing new modules.

Comment: Just check use "if oerr.Timeout() { ... some code to handle timeout ... } in your code

Comment: @Mikhail `oerr` has a concrete type, you cannot do type switches on concrete types, please fix your answer.

Comment: @mkopriva are you sure? it compiles, it runs and as far as I remember d.Dial returns "error" which is interface.

Comment: `oerr, ok := errors.(*net.OpError)` The errors var is an interface type, not oerr, oerr is *net.OpError that has an `error` field called Err.

Comment: @mkopriva, oh I see now. Yeah, it misses the .Err, thanks. Btw, the code with check for timeout is here https://pastebin.com/B3x8AwCW

Answer (score 0):

This code is not elegant but works now.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"
)

// Run the port scanner
func main() {
    var host, port string
    flag.StringVar(&host, "H", "", "host to scan")
    flag.StringVar(&port, "p", "", "port to scan")
    flag.Parse()

    if host == "" || port == "" {
        fmt.Println("Usage: portscan -H <host> -p port")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    d := net.Dialer{Timeout: 20*time.Second}
    conn, errors := d.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", host, port))
    if errors != nil {
        if oerr, ok := errors.(*net.OpError); ok {
            switch oerr.Err.(type) {
            case *os.SyscallError:
                fmt.Println("connect: connection refused to", host, "on port", port )
            default:
                if oerr.Timeout() {
                    fmt.Println("connect: connection timed out to", host, "on port", port )
                } else {
                    panic("Unknown connection error")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("connect: connection successful to", host, "on port", port )
    }

    if conn != nil {
        conn.Close()
    }
}
```